# Morphisms with an arbitrary number of objects

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Is this structure familiar for you?

It consists of

1. a category $C$

   a set $M$

   a function ``$\operatorname{arity}$'' defined on $M$

   a function $\operatorname{Obj}_m$ defined for every $m \in M$, such that
     $\operatorname{dom} \operatorname{Obj}_m = \operatorname{arity} m$

   a function (*star composition*) $\left( m ; f \right) \mapsto
     \operatorname{StarComp} \left( m ; f \right)$ defined for $m \in M$ and $f$ being an
     $(\operatorname{arity} m)$-indexed family of morphisms of $C$ such that $\forall i
     \in \operatorname{arity} m : \operatorname{Src} f_i = \operatorname{Obj}_m i$ ($\operatorname{Src} f_i$ is
     the source object of the morphism $f_i$) and $\operatorname{arity}\operatorname{StarComp} \left(
   m ; f \right) =\operatorname{arity}m$.

such that it holds:

1. $\operatorname{StarComp} \left( m ; f \right) \in M$

   (*associativiy law*)
     \[ \operatorname{StarComp} \left( \operatorname{StarComp} \left( m ; f \right) ; g \right) =
        \operatorname{StarComp} \left( m ; \lambda i \in \operatorname{arity} m : g_i \circ f_i
        \right) \]

(Here by definition $\lambda x \in D : F \left( x \right) = \left\{ \left( x ;
F \left( x \right) \right) \hspace{0.5em} | \hspace{0.5em} x \in D \right\}$.)

The meaning of the set $M$ is an extension of $C$ having as morphisms things
with arbitrary (possibly infinite) indexed set
$\operatorname{Obj}_m$ of objects, not just two objects as
morphims of $C$ have only source and destination).

We may also add the requirement that $\operatorname{StarComp}
\left( m ; \lambda i \in \operatorname{arity}m :
\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Obj}_m i} \right) =
m$ (*the law of composition with identity*).

Comment: Are you missing some indices in your associativity law? Specifically, $f$ and $g$ are indexed families of morphisms, so what does $g \circ f$ mean?

Comment: Eyeballing it, it looks like $M$ is intended to be a collection of formal "cartesian products" of objects, and when $(m;f)$ is defined, $f$ represents a formal morphism from $m$ to $\text{StarComp}(m;f)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Missing indexes added.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I'm not sure whether every "morphism" in $M$ can be obtained as a product. I rather deem not every morphism in $M$ is a product.

Comment: I'm not calling $M$ a set of *morphisms*, I'm calling $M$ a set of *objects*. It looks like you're extending $C$ by adding in a set $M$ of formal products of its objects, and defining a morphisms between any two elements of $M$ to be a list of arrows from $C$, one for each component of the domain.

Comment: P.S. the associativity rule seems to imply arity(m)$\subseteq$arity(Starcomp(m;f)). Are you supposed to have equality?

Comment: @Hurkyl: Elements of $M$ are generalized morphisms. Each element of $M$ has an indexed family of objects of $C$. These are not products.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yes: arity(m)=arity(Starcomp(m;f)).

Comment: It really, really looks like $m$ is supposed to be object-like and $(m;f)$ morphism-like. If you're sure that $m$ is supposed to be morphism-like, then I guess I don't see anything useful to say.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I am sure that $m$ is supposed to be morphism-like.

Comment: I know what's missing! There isn't a composition rule for two elements of $M$. So, if we're supposed to be thinking of $M$ as morphisms, then in terms of what you've described, only the codomain (given by Obj) of an element plays a role, and that's why it looks object-like to me.

Comment: Looks like a multicategory to me...